# Font gets changed in Android Studio preview but not in the device

Tags: android, text, coding-style, styles

I created a style which is applied to a `TextView`. It appears in Android Studio preview as I wanted to, but on the device it's different. What can I do?

This is XML code:

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
    style="@style/smalltextstyle"
        android:text="text here "
     />
</ScrollView>
```

This is my style code:

```
<style name="smalltextstyle">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textAlignment" tools:targetApi="jelly_bean_mr1">center</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">23sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
```

That's what it must be

[image: Expected appearance]

This is what appears

[image: Actual appearance]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this below class for your **customTextview** and in **assets folder download your fonts**

**xml**

Eg:

```
 <com.yourpackagename.font.MyTextView
                android:id="@+id/text_phone_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/text_phone_number"
                android:textColor="@color/colorDarkAsh_opacity"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>
```

**Class**

```
public class MyTextView extends AppCompatTextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        if (!isInEditMode()) {
            Typeface tf;

            switch (getTypeface().getStyle()) {
                case Typeface.BOLD:
                    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/AvenirLTMedium.otf");
                    break;

                case Typeface.ITALIC:
                    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/AvenirLTBookOblique.otf");
                    break;

                case Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC:
                    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/AvenirLTMediumOblique.otf");
                    break;

                case Typeface.NORMAL:
                    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/AvenirBook.otf");
                    break;

                default:
                    tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getContext().getAssets(), "fonts/AvenirBook.otf");
                    break;

            }

            setTypeface(tf);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a video tutorial because i am i beginner and i don't understand well

Comment: Hi, download sample fonts like AvenirBook.otf **https://github.com/joshwcomeau/Tori/blob/master/public/fonts/AvenirBook.otf**  put that in assests folder and call that in above **switch case** method.